# Conditional Drag Drop using DragControl in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to `activate`/`deactivate` the `DragControls` depending on the value of a flag `drag_flag`, but my approach doesn't work well!

can you please tell me how can I do that properly? thanks in advance.

```js
    var drag_flag = true;
    function change_drag_flag(){
      drag_flag = !drag_flag;
    }
    var objects = [];

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    let box_geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
    const box = new THREE.Mesh(box_geometry, material);
    objects.push(box);
    scene.add(box);

    var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
    spotLight.position.set(5, 5, 5);
    scene.add(spotLight);
    spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
    spotLight.position.set(-5, 5, 5);
    scene.add(spotLight);

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.1,
      1000
    );
    camera.position.set(0.1, 4, 1);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var drag_controls = new THREE.DragControls(objects, camera, renderer.domElement);
    if(drag_flag===true){
      drag_controls.activate();
      drag_controls.enabled = true;
    }
    else{
      drag_controls.deactivate();
      drag_controls.enabled = false;
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="change_drag_flag()">Change Drag Flag</button>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/examples/js/controls/DragControls.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rendering your scene only once so you don't see the effect of enabling/disabling the controls. I've slightly rewritten your code to make things work:

```js
const objects = [];

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const box_geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
const box = new THREE.Mesh(box_geometry, material);
objects.push(box);
scene.add(box);

const spotLight1 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
spotLight1.position.set(5, 5, 5);
scene.add(spotLight1);

const spotLight2 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
spotLight2.position.set(-5, 5, 5);
scene.add(spotLight2);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);
camera.position.set(0.1, 4, 1);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const dragControls = new THREE.DragControls(objects, camera, renderer.domElement);

function toggleDrag() {

  dragControls.enabled = !dragControls.enabled;

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  if (dragControls.enabled === true) {
    dragControls.activate();
  } else {
    dragControls.deactivate();
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

animate();
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="toggleDrag()" style="position:absolute">Change Drag Flag</button>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/examples/js/controls/DragControls.js"></script>
```